# Is safe to cast a dynamic array before passing it as a variable parameter?

Tags: arrays, delphi, casting, dynamic-arrays, delphi-2007

I have some functions which accepts an array of `TObject` as a `var` parameter, for example:

```
type
  TObjectArray = array of TObject;

...

procedure DeleteAt(var AArray : TObjectArray; AIndex : integer);
begin
  while(AIndex < Length(AArray) - 1) do
  begin
    AArray[AIndex] := AArray[AIndex + 1];
    Inc(AIndex);
  end;
  SetLength(AArray, Length(AArray) - 1);
end;
```

For reusing the same functions, I'm casting several dynamic array of `TObject`'s descendant classes to `TObjectArray` before passing them to my functions, for example:

```
var
  Buttons : array of TButton;
begin
  SetLength(Buttons, 1);
  Buttons[0] := Button1;

  //...

  DeleteAt(TObjectArray(Buttons), 0);
end;
```

Is this a safe practice or it could cause some problem that I didn't considered?

Comment: If you cast only TObject-compatible arrays, then it probably will work. But it is awful anyway. Why don't you use generic TList<T>?

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn: Because I'm using Delphi 2007

Comment: You can use regular classes TList / TObjectList.

Comment: Surely you can do better than this. But yes, that's going to work out.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: You need to encapsulate this better. So that you don't ask every single consumer of this code to perform such casts. Before generics we used classes to wrap his sort of hackery. Anyway, it's hard for me to get enthused for the pre generics language.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Understood. The point is that, without generics, I have to choose between a) this approach, which imply casting the whole array each time I use these functions b) using a TList or similar, which imply casting items each time I want to access their properties/methods... c) writing a class for each class of item I want to manage, which could be very time expensive. At this point, I think the only real solution would be that to upgrade all old projects I'm developing on and then use generics arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique itself doesn't cause harm provided the arrays are compatible. The members of an `array of TObject` are simply references to objects. Since objects can be used safely from an ancestor reference, there is no inherent problem.

Certainly the code you've shown in your question is safe. You could even `Free` the object instance you're removing/deleting if that makes sense in terms of your ownership pattern.

---

That said, there is a risk in that the compiler is unable to perform any of its typical type safety checks.

- In the extreme case, you're able to cast between for example `array of Byte` and `array of TObject`
- More subtly, you can accidentally cast between arrays of incompatible object types (e.g. cast between `array of TButton` and `array of TQuery`). When working with individual objects you have the option of a checked type-cast using `(<object> as <type>)`. This performs a compile-time check to verify the types are within the same hierarchy (otherwise cast is guaranteed to be incompatible), and a run-time check to ensure the object instance is actually of the correct type.
- Although removing and swapping objects in the array is safe, the **`var`** reference means you can *also add* objects to the array. Now whereas an `array of TButton` forces you to add `TButton` (or subclass) instances; having typecast to `array of TObject` means you can accidentally add any other object to the array. And when the function returns, code will attempt use objects *very incorrectly*. You're almost certain to get strange behaviour and/or access violations. They will be much more difficult to debug due to the *root problem* having been silently introduced earlier in the program.

---

### Conclusion

While the technique works, you'd be much better advised to use a `TObjectList`.

- This retains the standard object based type-checking.
- It supports similar use to an array, so is usually a great substitute.
- And as an extra bonus, the container is able dynamically resize as you add and remove items - no more manual resizing required.
- The only minor inconvenience is that you have to create and destroy the `TObjectList`.

*Even `TList` would be a generally better choice, though you'd have to perform unchecked casting between `Pointer` and class types.*

Comment: Thanks for explanation. In most cases, I still prefer arrays because otherwise I should create and free the list and cast items everytime I use them. Anyhow, you're answer has fully clarified all my doubts!